# Create Own Pod Library Swift and get ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm learning to make my own pod library, here is the link: https://github.com/ranggaleoo/LeoPopScreen

but when I run the command `pod lib lint` before releasing the pod, I get an error:

````
 -> LeoPopScreen (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in parallel
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'LeoPopScreen' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Pods-App' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Users/ranggaleo/Downloads/Project/LeoPopScreen/LeoPopScreen/LeoPopScreen/Classes/LeoPopScreen.xib:zyP-PG-5ZG: error: UIStackView before iOS 9.0 [6]
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')```


has anyone ever experienced? how to fix it?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Xcode 12, set the ios deployment target to at least 9.0:

`s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'`